# In American Sniper (2014), why didn't the team kill al Zarqawi?

Tags: american-sniper

In [American Sniper (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2179136/), why didn't they kill al Zarqawi?

The team killed Butcher but not al Zarqawi - they even declare themselves mission accomplished, but in this scene, officials announce the main aim of the mission is to kill Al Zarqawi:

[image: mission briefing screen capture from American Sniper]

Answer (score 2):

The reason they didn't kill al-Zarqawi is, quite simply, because Chris Kyle wasn't involved in the killing of al-Zarqawi.  The movie was *based* on Chris Kyle's memoirs, though it did differ in quite a few places.  One of them was the character of "The Butcher", who didn't actually exist.  However, they needed to provide an antagonist for Kyle's first couple of tours, so that character was created.